# In ADO boards can you get a User Stories status to be updated automatically when a child task's status moves to "In Progress"?

Tags: azure-devops, status, user-stories

I can not find a way to create a custom rule that will update a User Stories Status when a child tasks status changes to "In Progress".

Or when all child tasks are set to "Done" can the parent story status be set to Done automatically?

Checked all Custom Rule help

Answer (score 0):

There is  no custom rule for that, but you may use custom apps or scripts with Rest API for that. Examples:

1. [.Net App](https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/tree/master/CustomNetTasks/UpdateParentState)
2. [Logic App](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2020/01/08/automated-state-changing-with-azure-logic-app-of-parent-work-items-if-child-work-items-were-changed-on-azure-devops/)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use Power Automate

1. Create an automation that triggers when a "task" is updated
2. Gather the details of the updated item (This will easily show you the ID of the task, status of the task, & Parent ID which should point to the user story or PBI)
3. If status of the triggering task = "In progress" (or whatever you need), modify the parent item's status to "In progress" using the parent ID

I can mock this up if needed and share a screenshot but this should do the trick.